# Locally downloaded library not found by Gradle when compiled

Tags: java, maven, junit, gradle, nexus

I'm not used to post questions so please excuse my mistakes.

I'm looking into moving to Gradle+Nexus for my company and I've hit a wall.
I will try to describe my problem as clearly as possible.

I wrote 2 simple java programms, one depends on the other, both depends on junit to run theirs tests.
I could compile, test and run them while I was using Maven repository but one of the goals of using Nexus is to have 3rd party libraries on it as well as ours. While using Maven I could upload my builds to Nexus and also use them to compile with (through the dependencies) so no problem there.

But when I downloaded junit and uploaded it to Nexus I could not compile anymore.
Here is the error message I got:

> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':Project2:testCompile'.
>
> >Could not find junit.jar (junit:junit:4.12).
>
> Searched in the following locations:
>
> ```
>   http://mycompany/nexus/content/repositories/TRUNK_3rdParty/junit/junit/4.12/junit-4.12.jar
> ```

So gradle looks at the right place but cannot find junit.
I should mention that I uploaded junit using the POM file provided by Maven so everything should work.
As it might be of help, here are some code fragments from my build.gradle file:

```
repositories {
    maven {
        url "http://mycompany/nexus/content/repositories/TRUNK/"
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile group: 'mycompany', name: 'project1Nexus', version: '1.0-TEST'
}
```

that tells project2 where to find project1 on Nexus in order to compile (it works).

```
repositories {
    maven {
        url "http://mycompany/nexus/content/repositories/TRUNK_3rdParty/"
    }
}

dependencies {
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
}
```

and that should tell where to find junit but I get this error message.
Also the first repo/depend block is from the build.gradle file of project2 and the second one is from the one of the root folder. I doubt this could be an issue though as it worked fine when I used centralMaven.
If anyone had some insights to share, it would be amazing!
Cheers

Comment: Are you saying that if you change your repository URLs to mavenCentral everything works? If yes, then your nexus configuration is wrong then. Is your nexus setup to mirror internet repos? You shouldn't need to upload stuff yourself then.

Comment: No. We have setup to not mirror mavencentral. We uploaded it manually to control the libraries that are used. If we connect mavencentral for instance each developer can use every library and library version that is available. If we upload them manually to our repository and only use this repository, only the libraries contained in the repository can be used.
If we connect to mavencentral it works. However junit from our repository does not work. Our own coded artefacts that are published using gradle work as well. Only the self uploaded instance does not work.

Comment: To diagnose your issue I would mirror maven central and let nexus download the junit artefact. Then you can compare the POMs and artefact locations.

Comment: That's a good idea, I'll look into it, thanks. Also from what I found out so far it might be related to junit dependencies.